Magento2: upgrade 2.3.3 to 2.4.7-p2, multi website broken lands to 404
I recently upgraded my Magento 2.3.3 store to Magento 2.4.7-p2, and now I'm encountering an issue with the multi-website setup.
My Magento2 setup contains 2 websites: Default and Wholesale.
The Default website is functioning as usual.
I configured my 'Wholesale' website by duplicating the .htaccess and index.php files under the 'wholesale' directory on root, using the method described as the Second Option in the following link.
The Default website store is accessible at the following URL: https://mydomain.com/
Before the upgrade, my Wholesale website store was accessible at: https://mydomain.com/wholesale/
But now after the upgrade, the Wholesale website isn't accessible, appears to be broken, and leads to a 404 Not Found Page. :(
I would appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. Any suggestions are welcome.

I would never follow the duplicating solution. Refer to the other comment on the same link where you pass MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE that's the best way of doing it.

You can check the url_rewrite table for any entries where the request_path is empty. If you find any such entries, retrieve and remove them from the database using the following queries:
SELECT * FROM url_rewrite WHERE request_path=' ';
DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE request_path=' ';

After completing this, run the following commands:
php bin/magento c:f;
php bin/magento c:c;

